# Установка Windows 8 Mobile на смартфон HTC Desire C

Tags: windows, mobile

Посмотрел анонсы нового Windows 8 Mobile и подумал поставить его себе на Смарт.
Вопрос: Можно ли ставить на мой Смарт эту операционную систему.

Сейчас стоит Андроид последней версии (4.1), пока рад, но надо систему менее жрущую память.

Можно и не Виндовую ОС ставить. Просто хочу по скоростнее смарт сделать себе.

Comment: Windows mobile 8 как таковой нет. Вам приснилось. Windows Phone 8, к сожалению, не предоставляет возможности установки себя на другие телефоны. Алсо советую навсегда распрощаться с ведроидом и купить себе хорошенький Nokia lumia 920 :3 Совершенный телефон.

Comment: а как вы определяете факт: 

> Сейчас стоит Андроид последней версии (4.1), пока рад, но надо систему менее жрущую память.
> 

андройд и линукс с ОП работают иначе чем винда

Comment: Да, ошибся !. С другом на работе прост обсуждали .. он спросил "Можно ли ставить?" ))) недолго думая - создал вопрос :Р

Comment: а как определяю ! Проц на 900 мегагерц (как мой первый комп) но тянет не сильно быстро он ... перегружается смарт если долго его не ребутать !...

Comment: скажу честно не сравнивал новую винду и андроид 4, но точно помню андройд жрёт проц(из-за виртуальной машины) а ОП наоборот эффективно использует, винда же(6.5) наоборот... 

так вот: точно помню что через рут можно настроить вирт машину так что она раза в 4 меньше жрать будет... 

а вот в винде беду с ОП не исправишь хоть ты тресни...

погугли на 4pda и в инете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще вам не сюда (хешкод) а вот сюда:

- [HTC Desire C](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=328268)
- [перепрошивка HTC Desire C](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=369334)

4pda как раз специализируется на всём, что связано с телефонами.

Comment: да, я знаю что на 4pda есть много чего интересного, но лучше ответит человек кто компетентен в вопросах чем я щас полезу и накосячу =)